# Sentence /idiom describing overmarketing a product which is of little value

Tags: idioms, sentence

How do you describe something which has value but little value but exaggerating that it the best and solves all major problems,someone is overdoing/overmarketing his product

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [hype](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hype?s=t) which can be used as a verb or a noun.

Verb

> to create interest in by flamboyant or dramatic methods; promote or
>   publicize showily: a promoter who knows how to hype a prizefight.
>   to intensify (advertising, promotion, or publicity) by ingenious or
>   questionable claims, methods, etc. (usually followed by up). to trick;
>   gull.

Noun

> exaggerated publicity; hoopla.
>    an ingenious or questionable
>   claim, method, etc., used in advertising, or            publicity to
>   intensify
>  the effect.
>  a swindle, deception, or trick.

You could say for instance:

> It's all hype. The product isn't worth that much.
>
> They over-hyped the product.

Answer (score 0):

**piddling**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/piddling) idiom

> mod. inadequate; meager; tiny. (see also piss-poor, piddle.)

As in:

> That is a piddling product.